# How to set JSON format to HTML5 data attributes in the jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying these HTML

```
<div data-params="{a: 1, b: '2'}" id="TEST1"></div>
<div data-params='{"a": 1, "b": "2"}' id="TEST2"></div>
```

Then I use data() method in the jQuery

```
$('#TEST1').data('params'); //return a string
$('#TEST2').data('params'); //return a object
```

But TEST1 it's not a return object, but a string, it can only return object TEST2.
But I want to get a object by TEST1, How do I do it?

=============

Finally, I choose to write a function to achieve their own needs

```
$.fn.data2 = function(key, value)
{
    if (value === undefined) 
    {
        var data = $(this).data(key);
        if (typeof(data) === 'string') 
        {
            var _data = data.replace(/^[\s\r\n]*/g, '').replace(/[\s\r\n]*$/g, '');
            if (_data.match(/\{.*\}/) || _data.match(/\[.*\]/)) {
                try {
                    _data = (new Function( 'return ' + data ))();
                    if (typeof(_data) == 'object') {
                        $(this).data(key, _data);
                        data = _data;
                    }
                } catch(ex) {}
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    return $(this).data(key, value);
};
```

Comment: But why I try to use jquery.metadata plugin is to working?

Comment: Is there a way to get jQuery to parse the same as the first HTML jquery.metadata plugin?

Answer (score 36):

In order to be parsed as an object, the data attribute must be a **well formed JSON object**.

In your case you just need to quote the object keys (as you do in the second object). Try:

```
<div data-params='{"a": 1, "b": "2"}' id="TEST1"></div>
```

For more info see the [data method docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/), the relevant part is this one (emphasis mine):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value
>   (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null) otherwise
>   it is left as a string... ...When the
>   data attribute is an object (starts with `'{'`) or array (starts with
>   `'['`) then `jQuery.parseJSON` is used to parse the string; **it must follow
>   valid JSON syntax including quoted property names.**

Comment: For what it's worth, I think JSON is so strict that even using single quotes instead of double quotes is invalid.

Comment: @joe perhaps that plugin parser is not as strict as jQuery's. I'd use the keys with quotes just to be sure.

Comment: Is there a way to get jQuery to parse the same as the first HTML jquery.metadata plugin?

Comment: No, I guess you could try older versions of jQuery that weren't so strict... butI don't know if they support the HTML5 custom data attribs.

Comment: Whell... Doing parameter like this i even don`t nead to pass throguht jQuery.parseJSON() function :D (at least for $ 1.9.1 and above).

Comment: If json data has ' character then json cannot read from attribute.

Answer (score 7):

You can escape the inner quotes:

```
<div data-params="{&quot;a&quot;: 1, &quot;b&quot;: &quot;2&quot;}" id="TEST2"></div>
```

But there is nothing wrong with your second method:

```
<div data-params='{"a": 1, "b": "2"}' id="TEST2"></div>
```

I would use that.

Comment: Is there a way to get jQuery to parse the same as the first HTML jquery.metadata plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It's how Uikit parse data attribute json. Hope this will helpful

```js
function str2json(str, notevil) {
  try {
    if (notevil) {
      return JSON.parse(str
                        .replace(/([\$\w]+)\s*:/g, function(_, $1){return '"'+$1+'":';})
                        .replace(/'([^']+)'/g, function(_, $1){return '"'+$1+'"';})
                       );
    } else {
      return (new Function("", "var json = " + str + "; return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));"))();
    }
  } catch(e) { return false; }
}

function options(string) {
  if (typeof string !='string') return string;

  if (string.indexOf(':') != -1 && string.trim().substr(-1) != '}') {
    string = '{'+string+'}';
  }

  var start = (string ? string.indexOf("{") : -1), options = {};

  if (start != -1) {
    try {
      options = str2json(string.substr(start));
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  return options;
}

var paramsData = document.querySelectorAll('[data-params]')[0].dataset.params;

var optionsParsed = options(paramsData);

console.log(optionsParsed);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
  <div data-params="{hello: 'world'}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```